# Linking start button from html to javascript function to perform prompt to start game, prompt starts on page start

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a very basic rock paper scissors shoot game where you can play vs. the computer using JavaScript functions.

I have a very basic skeleton of HTML that has a button. I am trying to launch the prompt (game) when pressed.

The prompt works the way I want it but it starts the script once I open the window.

I am trying to start the script only when the button on the html is pressed.

I get an error on the console when I press the button

> getPlayerChoice is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Here is my code:

```js
let playerWinCount = 0;
let computerWinCount = 0;
let roundCount = 0;

function playRound() {
function computerPlay() {
    let arr = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    let compChoice = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        return compChoice;
}

//function getPlayerChoice() {
    var str = prompt("What is your selection for this round?");
    if (!str) {
        return;
}
    let newStr = str.toLowerCase();
    let capStr = newStr[0].toUpperCase() + newStr.slice(1);
        if (capStr !== "Rock" && capStr!== "Paper" && capStr !== "Scissors") {
        return;
} else {
        return capStr;
    }
}
//
    let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();            
        if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        alert("Try again... You both chose " + playerSelection + "!");
        return;
} else {
        if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        alert("You win! Rock beats Scissors!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;

} else if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        alert("You lose! Paper beats Rock!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
    }
    
} else  if (playerSelection === "Paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
        alert("You win! Paper beats Rock!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
    
} else if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        alert("You lose! Scissors beats Paper!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
}
} else if (playerSelection === "Scissors") {
        if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
        alert("You lose! Rock beats Scissors!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
} else if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        alert("You win! Scissors beats Paper!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
            }
        }
    }
}
//

function game() {
    while (roundCount < 5) {
        playRound();
    }
    if (playerWinCount > computerWinCount) {
        alert("Player wins! The score was " + playerWinCount + " - " + computerWinCount);
    } else if (computerWinCount > playerWinCount) {
        alert("Computer wins! The score was " + computerWinCount + " - " + playerWinCount);
    } else {
        alert("Something crazy happened and I have no idea who won!");
    }
}

game();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Rock-Paper-Scissors - Odin project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="Start Game" type="button" value="Start Game" onclick="getPlayerChoice();" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I commented out my prompt function because whenever the program runs, it launches the prompt which can't be closed.

I need a way to close the prompt window out if there is no input.

Comment: you have the line that defines the function getPlayerChoice commented out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run the `game` function when the Start Game button is clicked, instead of running it on page load.

```
<input id="Start Game" type="button" value="Start Game" onclick="game();" />
```

Live Example:

```js
let playerWinCount = 0;
let computerWinCount = 0;
let roundCount = 0;

function playRound() {
  function computerPlay() {
    let arr = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    let compChoice = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    return compChoice;
  }

  function getPlayerChoice() {
    var str = prompt("What is your selection for this round?");
    if (!str) {
      return;
    }
    let newStr = str.toLowerCase();
    let capStr = newStr[0].toUpperCase() + newStr.slice(1);
    if (capStr !== "Rock" && capStr !== "Paper" && capStr !== "Scissors") {
      return;
    } else {
      return capStr;
    }
  }
  //
  let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    alert("Try again... You both chose " + playerSelection + "!");
    return;
  } else {
    if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
      if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        alert("You win! Rock beats Scissors!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;

      } else if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        alert("You lose! Paper beats Rock!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
      }

    } else if (playerSelection === "Paper") {
      if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
        alert("You win! Paper beats Rock!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;

      } else if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        alert("You lose! Scissors beats Paper!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
      }
    } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors") {
      if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
        alert("You lose! Rock beats Scissors!");
        computerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Computer wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
      } else if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        alert("You win! Scissors beats Paper!");
        playerWinCount++;
        roundCount++;
        console.log("Player wins! Current score: Player-" + playerWinCount + ", Computer-" + computerWinCount);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
//

function game() {
  while (roundCount < 5) {
    playRound();
  }
  if (playerWinCount > computerWinCount) {
    alert("Player wins! The score was " + playerWinCount + " - " + computerWinCount);
  } else if (computerWinCount > playerWinCount) {
    alert("Computer wins! The score was " + computerWinCount + " - " + playerWinCount);
  } else {
    alert("Something crazy happened and I have no idea who won!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="Start Game" type="button" value="Start Game" onclick="game()" />
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still starts as soon as the page loads. Not sure which part of the code I need to change on the script to prevent it from starting on the load rather than the click.

Comment: Remove `game()` from your JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisR. Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/v89n35fs/

Comment: That makes sense now, I appreciate it!

Comment: @ChrisR. No problem.